# How to observe all models implementing an interface in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have an audit class which extends the *Eloquent Model*...

```
class Audit extends Model {
}
```

I have an auditable interface...

```
interface IAuditiable {
    public function audit();
}
```

I have a trait which fulfils the interface and defines the relation between the model and the audit...

```
trait Auditable {
    public function audit(){
        return $this->hasMany('Audit');
    }
}
```

I have a model which extends the Eloquent Model implements the interface and uses the trait...

```
class Post extends Model implements IAuditable {
    use Auditable;
}
```

I'd like to add the functionality in there to `create` or `update` an audit whenever the Post model is created or updated. I've solved this by registering an observer on the Post which would catch the 'saved' event and add a new audit.

However, there will eventually be many models using implementing `IAuditable` and using the `Auditable` trait.

So, my question is, is it possible to implement an observer which would pick up all 'saved' events for any model which implements the `IAuditable` interface in *Laravel 5.1*?

Comment: Have you considered something like https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable ?

Comment: You could make your own Model contract which implements the added functionality to the saved function, and have your Auditable models extend AuditableModel

Comment: Yes, @Brynn that seems like the only solution at the moment. This is what Venture Craft in their revisionable solution. I'm not keen on this because 1) I don't want the added complexity of additional inheritance 2) there may be other updates in future that need to extend the saved method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try hooking into eloquent events. Do something like this in a service provider:

```
Event::listen(['eloquent.created: *', 'eloquent.updated: *'], function($model) {
    // Check if the model implements your interface (could use class_implements(...)  
});
```

I had to do something very similar to what you're looking to do. This solution isn't perfect because you catch events from *every* model, but it works well enough.

**EDIT**: Just noticed this question was asked almost two years ago. Hopefully this helps someone out, though :)

Comment: Helped me out ! Thanks :)